# use_module in XSB Prolog

Tags: http, prolog, porting, swi-prolog, xsb

I am porting http libraries from SWI Prolog to XSB Prolog. I have to port the following statement:

```
use_module(library(settings)).
```

to XSB. Can someone please tell me how to do this. I understand that porting is not trivial. I need to use `set_setting, current_setting` etc. I am not sure if there is an equivalent function existing in XSB.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That will not be an easy port. See [the doc](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/settings.pl). Good luck!

Comment: @false. Above link appears to be broken. Sad!